# How to manage a function of a third-party library that stops returning value after a while?

Tags: python, chatgpt-api

A function, namely, the `prompt` function of my [GPT4All](https://github.com/nomic-ai/gpt4all) object stops returning value after a while (I process a bunch of queries) without any errors/exceptions. I've tried to set a timeout to that function's execution but this control has caused the `[Errno 32] Broken pipe` error as I write the returned value of this prompt function to a `CSV` file.

So, I'd like to get your recommendations to overcome this situation by simply skipping that iteration and continue processing other inputs.

Here is my script that I've added a comment on the call that stops returning a value after a while:

```
from nomic.gpt4all import GPT4All
import csv
from time import time   


CMU_CSV_PATH = 'data/cmu_qa.csv'

def single_chatgpt_offline(gpt, question):
    try:
        print(f'\tAsking {question}')
        resp = gpt.prompt(question)  # ----> This call stops returning a result after a while
        print(f'\tGot the response: {resp}')
        return resp
    except Exception as err:
        print(f'{str(err)}')

    return None

def find_answers_and_write_csv():
    # initialize GPT4
    gpt = GPT4All()
    gpt.open()

    with open(CMU_CSV_PATH, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csv_src:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_src)

        with open('data/cmu_qa_answers.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as csv_target:
            fields = ['question', 'answer', 'title', 'bard', 'bard_time', 'gpt', 'gpt_time']
            csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_target, fieldnames=fields)
            # write the header
            csv_writer.writeheader()

            for idx, line in enumerate(csv_reader):
                question = line['question']
                line['title'] = line['title'].replace('_', ' ')

                # GPT
                duration_gpt_start = time()
                resp_gpt = single_chatgpt_offline(gpt, question)
                if resp_gpt and '\n' in resp_gpt:
                    resp_gpt = resp_gpt.replace('\n', ' ')
                duration_gpt_end = time()
                line['gpt'] = resp_gpt
                line['gpt_time'] = round((duration_gpt_end - duration_gpt_start), NUM_DECIMAL)

                line["bard"] = None
                line["bard_time"] = None

                csv_writer.writerow(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import signal
def single_chatgpt_offline(gpt, question, timeout=10):
    try:
        print('Asking {}'.format(question))
    
        signal.alarm(timeout)
    
        resp = gpt.prompt(question)
        print('Got the response: {}'.format(resp))
        return resp
    except Exception as err:
        print(f'{str(err)}')
    finally:
        signal.alarm(0)

    return None
```

Check if this works : Adding a timeout for the prompt function. If the timeout is elapsed you jump to the except block, which allows you to process other inputs.

Finally block disables the current assigned timeout so that other calls to the prompt function are not affected.

Comment: The execution finished after a while with getting the message as follows: `Process finished with exit code 142 (interrupted by signal 14: SIGALRM)`

Comment: Did you try by increasing the timeout?

Comment: This error is thrown when the necessary timeout control is triggered. So, increasing the timeout did not change the end result.